# Help in Stats, Joint p.d.f

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables that have a joint p.d.f., which is given by the formula $\displaystyle p_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{5e^{−5x}}{x}$ when $0< y < x < \infty$, and $p_{X,Y}(x,y)=0$ for all other $x$ and $y$. Find Cov$(X,Y)$.

Comment: Cov$(X,Y)=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the covariance as $E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]$.

Then, use the definition of expectation: $E[XY] = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} xy p_{X,Y}(x,y) dx dy$

$E[X] = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} x p_{X,Y}(x,y) dx dy$

$E[Y] = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} y p_{X,Y}(x,y) dx dy$

or equivalently for the latter two, 
$p_X(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} p_{X,Y}(x,y) dy$

$p_Y(y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} p_{X,Y}(x,y) dx$

$E[X] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x p_X(x) dx$

$E[Y] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} y p_Y(y) dy$